# Can a ceiling fan brace/box be in direct contact with insulation?

Tags: electrical, insulation

New work.

Installing a ceiling fan in unfinished basement room.

Can a ceiling fan brace/box be in direct contact with batt insulation? I know recessed light housings can't, unless they're IC rated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ceiling fan electrical box would not generate any heat in normal operation. It should be fine to have it in contact with insulating batts.

Comment: Agree there is no heat in the fan box so it can be in contact.